# Primeng p-calendar goes behind modal dialog on second click

Tags: angular, primeng

I have a very simple p-calendar that is showing on a modal dialog. Since the dialog is not very big, I'm using appendTo="body". However, if the user clicks twice into the input area of the control, the calendar goes behind the dialog. The only way I've been able to fix is to remove the appendTo, but then my modal has to be too big. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm using 4.3.0 btw.

Comment: you can always customise your css style without removing any attribute. But you have to wrap under the following css tag :host::ng-deep {   .ui-column-title {
    color: $clr-white;
  }  }   // the above is just example. Use your calendar css tag to override